# Store date without time in SQL database where datatype is datetime

Tags: sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing the date Only in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320694/storing-the-date-only-in-sql-server-2005)

I am using SQL Server 2005 database. When I store a date there is only `datetime` as datatype for dates, so whenever I remove time from date and store it in database it takes the default time but I want to get it store as only date and not time

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320694/storing-date-only-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: In SQL Server 2005, you **cannot** store just the DATE - there simply is no "just DATE" datatype... SQL Server 2005 has its "end-of-life" in April - why don't you upgrade to a more recent version?

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade to SQL Server 2008 which has a date datatype. Otherwise just let it put in the time as midnight and ignore it when querying. The one thing you do NOT want to do is store it as a varchar or nvarchar.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to store the value as a datetime and just ignore the time part.

You could create a user-defined type as described in this [blog post](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/31/sql-server-2005-date-time-only-data-types.aspx) but it seems more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an int instead of a Datetime, Or, you could create your own datatype

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyDateType] FROM [int]
```

And just cast dates to/from this datatype

```
Declare @Dt Datetime Set @dt = '11 June 2011 08:00'
Declare @MyDt int 
Set @MyDt = Cast(@dt as int)
Select Cast (@MyDt as DateTime)
```

or using the custom data type...

```
Declare @Dt Datetime Set @dt = '11 June 2011 08:00'
Declare @MyDt MyDateType
Set @MyDt = Cast(@dt as MyDateType)
Select Cast (@MyDt as DateTime)
```